# how to make SVG LinearGradient invariant

Tags: reactjs, svg, gradient, react-flow

I am complete beginer in SVG and React, I am working on a reactflow app to design a low-code tool to produce DAGs.

I have nodes with different colors for source and target handles and I used this medium [article](https://medium.com/@raivaibhav08/change-react-flow-edge-color-to-gradient-bc303c6845b9) to produce custom edges with a linear gradient

Correct edge color gradient:

[image: correct edge color gradient]

My problem is that when the source is moved below the target the linear gradient changes orientation and I get the following

Incorrect edge color gradient:

[image: incorrect edge color gradient]

I'd like the linear gradient to be invariant with respect to the source and target position.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: the medium article provides a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/interesting-dan-i9j8eg) which illustrates my problem: moving node 5 above node 4 inverts the gradient

Comment: I suggest editing this question to include a [mcve] as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I added a link to a codesandbox nearly minimal example

Answer (score 0):

Question solved

I defined a function that checks the relative position of the nodes and adjust the gradient style correspondingly.

```
function adjustStyle(sourceY,targetY) {
    // Check if source is below target
    let style;
    if (sourceY < targetY) {
      style = {stroke: 'url(#edgegradient1)'};
      }
    else {
      style = {stroke: 'url(#edgegradient2)'};
    }
    return style;
  }
```

I added a call to this function into the `CustomEdge.js` script

```
import React from 'react';
import { getBezierPath } from 'reactflow';

export default function CustomEdge({id,sourceX,sourceY,targetX,targetY,
                                    sourcePosition,targetPosition,
                                    style = {},data,markerEnd,}) {

const newstyle=adjustStyle(sourceY,targetY);
const [edgePath] = getBezierPath({sourceX,sourceY,sourcePosition,
                                  targetX,targetY,targetPosition,});
return (
  <>
    <path
      id={id}
      style={newstyle}
      className="react-flow__edge-path"
      d={edgePath}
      markerEnd={markerEnd}
    />
    <text>
      <textPath
        href={`#${id}`}
        style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}
        startOffset="50%"
        textAnchor="middle"
      >
        {data.text}
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </>
);
}
```

`edgegradient1` and `edgegradient2` being defined by

```
export default function GradientEdge1() {
    return (
      <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style={{ height: 0, width: 0 }}>
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="edgegradient1" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
            <stop offset="5%" stopColor="gold" />
            <stop offset="95%" stopColor="red" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
      </svg>
    );
  }
```

and

```
export default function GradientEdge2() {
    return (
      <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style={{ height: 0, width: 0 }}>
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="edgegradient2" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
            <stop offset="5%" stopColor="red" />
            <stop offset="95%" stopColor="gold" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
      </svg>
    );
  }
```